# Add extra data in textextjs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-textext

I'm trying to call a funtion in  textextjs method-

```
//my function
function GetAreaTags() {
    return "some text";
}

//textext initializtion
$('#territory').textext({
    plugins: 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax',
    ajax: {
         url: '/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=' + GetAreaTags(),
         dataType: 'json',
         cacheResults: false
    }
});
```

But **GetAreaTags()** is not being called. How can i make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

It should work... But try this:

```
function GetAreaTags() {
    return "some text";
};
var yourObj= {
    plugins: 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax',
    ajax : {
      url: '/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=' + GetAreaTags(),
      dataType: 'json',
      cacheResults: false
    }
};
$('#territory').textext(yourObj);
console.log(yourObj.ajax.url);
```

If that doesn't work out try this:

```
function GetAreaTags() {
    return "some text";
};
var yourObj= {
    plugins: 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax',
    ajax : {
      url: function() {return '/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=' + GetAreaTags()},
      dataType: 'json',
      cacheResults: false
    }
};
$('#territory').textext(yourObj);
console.log(yourObj.ajax.url);
```

Check the console both times to see if your url is what you desire.

[EDIT: I rejected the edit by mistake, sorry about that]

### Edit2

From s.k.paul's comment:

> GetAreaTags() should execute every time i type in that textbox.
>   However, console says- 1. /Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=
>   2. localhost:12788/Admin/Dashboard/…}&q= 404 (Not Found)

Therefore you need another event handler to dynamically change the url (the plugin must be recalled with another url):

```
function GetAreaTags() {
    return "some text";
};
$("#territory").keyup(function() {
    var yourObj= {
        plugins: 'tags prompt focus autocomplete ajax',
        ajax : {
          url: function() {return '/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=' + GetAreaTags()},
          dataType: 'json',
          cacheResults: false
        }
    };
    $('#territory').textext(yourObj);
    console.log(yourObj.ajax.url);
});
```

However, this may be very heavy... The plugin expects you to have a single reference for your auto-complete resource. If you're dynamically changing it, it may reset the already existing stuff.

### Edit3

> Edit 2 : textextjs does not work at all now. And, url function returns
>   whole function text

This means the plugin doesn't handle well being recalled twice or more times in the same element. The only possible solution I am seeing is to change the plugin's code in order to dynamically change the resources according to your function...

Which makes me wonder, if it's easier for you to allow the user to have a broader data resource (include all areas) when typing, this way there would be only one URL and the plugin wouldn't have any trouble with that.

Comment: @s.k.paul can you describe the console's output? I tried this in my own console and the url comes out like this `/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=some text`. Is the textExt plugin giving any error?

Comment: GetAreaTags() should execute every time i type in that textbox. However, console says- 

1. /Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=


2. http://localhost:12788/Admin/Dashboard/function%20()%20%7B%20return%20'/Admin/Search/GetTerritorySuggestions?area=%27%20+%20GetAreaTags()%20}&q= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @s.k.paul oh... so the problem is a different one. If you want it to execute everytime you type something, that will not work, since the plugin expects the url parameter to be static (the same). The immediate solution is to to call the textExt method if the url changes. I will edit my answer according to your reply.

Comment: Edit 2 : textextjs does not work at all now. And, url function returns whole function text.

Comment: @s.k.paul ok, that means the plugin is not expecting to be recalled in the same element. The only solution for this is to alter the plugin to call your function and change the resources dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85297/discussion-between-s-k-paul-and-armfoot).